# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.user')

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am slowly learning ReactNative as part of a school project

After fixing my previous problem which I got help from on here I ran into another problem. All the this.state's on the settings page were originally this.setState and I changed it because I thought that was the reason for my problem, but the problem kept persisting

Any help would be great and again I appreciate all the help I have gotten from this community so far

**Mock screen**

```
import Fire from '../utilities/Fire';
import React from "react";

class mock extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
    this.state = {
       user: {},
    }

  }
    componentDidMount() {
      const user = this.props.uid || Fire.shared.uid

      this.unsubscribe = Fire.shared.firestore
          .collection("users")
          .doc(user)
          .onSnapshot(doc => {
              this.setState({ user: doc.data() });
          });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
      this.unsubscribe();

  }

  unsubscribe = null;

};  


  const profile = {
    name: this.state.user.name,
    location: this.state.user.location,
    email: this.state.user.email,
    avatar: this.state.user.avatar ? { uri: this.state.user.avatar } : require("../assets/avatar.png"),
    notifications: true,
  };



export {profile, mock};
```

**SettingsScreen**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Image, StyleSheet, ScrollView, TextInput } from "react-native";

import { Divider, Button, Block, Text, Switch } from "../components";
import { theme, mock } from "../constants";

class Settings extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      notifications: true,
      editing: null,
      user: {}
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    const user = this.props.uid || Fire.shared.uid

    this.unsubscribe = Fire.shared.firestore
        .collection("users")
        .doc(user)
        .onSnapshot(doc => {
            this.setState({ user: doc.data() });
        });
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    this.unsubscribe();

}

unsubscribe = null;


  handleEdit(name, text) {
    const { user } = this.state;
    user[name] = text;

    this.state({ user });
  }

  toggleEdit(name) {
    const { editing } = this.state;
    this.state({ editing: !editing ? name : null });
  }

  renderEdit(name) {
    const { user, editing } = this.state;

    if (editing === name) {
      return (
        <TextInput
          defaultValue={user[name]}
          onChangeText={text => this.handleEdit([name], text)}
        />
      );
    }

    return <Text bold>{user[name]}</Text>;
  }

  render() {
    const { user, editing } = this.state;

    return (
      <Block>
        <Block flex={false} row center space="between" style={styles.header}>
          <Text h1 bold>
            Settings
          </Text>
          <Button>
            <Image source={user.avatar} style={styles.avatar} />
          </Button>
        </Block>

        <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
          <Block style={styles.inputs}>
            <Block row space="between" margin={[10, 0]} style={styles.inputRow}>
              <Block>
                <Text gray2 style={{ marginBottom: 10 }}>
                  Name
                </Text>
                {this.renderEdit("name")}
              </Block>
              <Text
                medium
                secondary
                onPress={() => this.toggleEdit("username")}
              >
                {editing === "username" ? "Save" : "Edit"}
              </Text>
            </Block>
            <Block row space="between" margin={[10, 0]} style={styles.inputRow}>
              <Block>
                <Text gray2 style={{ marginBottom: 10 }}>
                  Location
                </Text>
                {this.renderEdit("location")}
              </Block>
              <Text
                medium
                secondary
                onPress={() => this.toggleEdit("location")}
              >
                {editing === "location" ? "Save" : "Edit"}
              </Text>
            </Block>
            <Block row space="between" margin={[10, 0]} style={styles.inputRow}>
              <Block>
                <Text gray2 style={{ marginBottom: 10 }}>
                  E-mail
                </Text>
                <Text bold>{user.email}</Text>
              </Block>
            </Block>
          </Block>

          <Divider margin={[theme.sizes.base, theme.sizes.base * 2]} />
          <Divider />

          <Block style={styles.toggles}>
            <Block
              row
              center
              space="between"
              style={{ marginBottom: theme.sizes.base * 2 }}
            >
              <Text gray2>Notifications</Text>
              <Switch
                value={this.state.notifications}
                onValueChange={value => this.state({ notifications: value })}
              />
            </Block>
          </Block>
        </ScrollView>
      </Block>
    );
  }
}

Settings.defaultProps = {
  user: mock.user
};

export default Settings;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  header: {
    paddingHorizontal: theme.sizes.base * 2
  },
  avatar: {
    height: theme.sizes.base * 2.2,
    width: theme.sizes.base * 2.2
  },
  inputs: {
    marginTop: theme.sizes.base * 0.7,
    paddingHorizontal: theme.sizes.base * 2
  },
  inputRow: {
    alignItems: "flex-end"
  },
  sliders: {
    marginTop: theme.sizes.base * 0.7,
    paddingHorizontal: theme.sizes.base * 2
  },
  thumb: {
    width: theme.sizes.base,
    height: theme.sizes.base,
    borderRadius: theme.sizes.base,
    borderColor: "white",
    borderWidth: 3,
    backgroundColor: theme.colors.secondary
  },
  toggles: {
    paddingHorizontal: theme.sizes.base * 2
  }
});
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. In the first snippet it's not clear what you thought this would be inside the profile object, which isn't inside the class

Comment: I'd suggest reading the linked article.

Comment: What is `this` supposed to refer to in `const profile = {
    name: this.state.user.name,`? You're not within a class declaration, so, it's the global object, which generally does not have a `state` property.

Comment: @CoreyRot repduce you code example here https://codesandbox.io/dashboard

Comment: @hereticmonkey this was going to refer to the this.state up in the constructor but because when i would put the const in the class it was come up with an error of "profile is not defined because it would only be able to define the one class which is mock so that is why i thought putting it out of the class would make it work

Comment: Well, just goes to show, you can't move code wherever you want :). I don't think you need the `profile` object. You're using React, and that has solutions for handling state that you should use.

Comment: i'm sorry i'm new to the whole react-native scene

Comment: That's not related to React Native, just JavaScript.